# Ошибка при использывании ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Почему мне выбивает ошибку

```
Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Student_list, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 253]
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
```

Когда пытаюсь скомпилировать этот кусок:

```
CREATE VIEW [Student_list] AS
    SELECT  [Student].[group_id]AS [Group №],
            [first_name]    AS [First name],
            [last_name]     AS [Last name],
            [e-mail]        AS [E-mail],
            [mobile_number] AS [Mobile number],
            [Level].[name]   AS [Level],
            [Language].[name]AS [Language]
    FROM [Student]
    INNER JOIN [Group] ON [Group].group_id = Student.group_id
    INNER JOIN [Level] ON [Group].level_id = [Level].level_id
    INNER JOIN [Language] ON [Group].language_id = [Language].language_id
    ORDER BY Student.group_id
GO
```

Когда удаляю строку с `ORDER BY`, то всё хорошо работает.

Можно как-то исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Вы прочитали сообщение об ошибке? Какую задачу Вы пытаетесь решить, используя `ORDER BY` внутри `CREATE VIEW`?

Comment: я хотел отсортировать VIEW, но я уже нашёл информации что в этом нет смысл, вопрос закрыт